# Differentiate $5(\sqrt{x})(x^3−5\sqrt{x}+5)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I don't exactly remember how to approach this problem:

> $5(\sqrt{x})(x^3−5\sqrt{x}+5)$

However, I know that derivatives of the Xs are:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x} &\to \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \\
x^3−5 \sqrt{x} +5 &\to  3 x^2- \frac{5}{2\sqrt{x}}+0
\end{align*}

I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

Oh and I don't think I need to use the definition of a derivative on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take all of $5\sqrt x$ as one factor.  So let's call $f(x) = 5\sqrt x$ and $g(x) = x^3−5 \sqrt{x} +5$ 
Then use the product rule: $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$

Comment: It comes out with a seemingly long problem due to the product rule. Every time I see it, my mind thinks I did something wrong.

Comment: That happens sometimes. Very often, though, we can simplify.

Answer (score 1):

While it's <strike>important</strike> essential that you know the product rule, you can make the problem a bit simpler by distributing the $\sqrt{x}$ first.  (Or for that matter, the $5\sqrt{x}$; I'll leave the $5$ out for this demonstration, though.)  So, $5(\sqrt{x})(x^3−5\sqrt{x}+5)=5(x^{7/2}-5x+5\sqrt{x})$.  And since $(5\cdot f)'=5\cdot f'$, you can simply differentiate the parenthesized bit and multiply the result by $5$. This might prove a useful check while you absorb the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

OK you have to use the fact that $  (f(x)\cdot g(x))' = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) $ where $f(x)=5(\sqrt{x}) $ and $ g(x)= (x^3−5\sqrt{x}+5) $. You should really read you basic rules you know.